# Microsoft.BingAds.SDK for .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, bing

I am trying to download `Install-Package Microsoft.BingAds.SDK` using nuget packager manager console but it only supports for .net 4.5 version.

I go through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/bing-ads-overview-getting-started-csharp-visual-basic-with-web-services.aspx#requirements) documentation but it is mentioned here for only .net framework 4.5 or later. Which version of `Microsoft.BingAds.SDK` supports for .net 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the Microsoft.BingAds.SDK NuGet packages support .NET 4.0. All versions require .NET 4.5